# James Webb hot temperature

Tags: james-webb-space-telescope

The warmest part of JWST is still hotter (41 $^\circ$C) than me.
What I don't understand is where it became so hot (it's been well over 50 $^\circ$C for a long time), and why the hottest point doesn't cool faster.

Is there a napkin friendly calculation to understand how much heat escapes JWST?

Comment: It’s been sitting in direct sunlight for several weeks…

Comment: @PeterErwin And never in the shade.

Comment: The effective equilibrium temperature of a flat plane that is always face-on to the Sun with the same albedo as the Earth and that orbits about 1 AU from the Sun is $\sqrt 2$ times the absolute effective equilibrium temperature of the Earth. That makes that flat plane have an effective equilibrium temperature of about 360 kelvins, or about 87° C.

Comment: I think that already constitutes 60% of an answer, if not a full one @DavidHammen